# Attaching a named in-memory database from C api

Tags: c, sqlite

Is it possible to attach a named SQLite3 `:memory:` database using the C API? There is of course `sqlite3_open`, but how do I set the name to be used in queries? Also, I could attach it by executing the `ATTACH DATABASE` statement, but then how do I get hold of its DB pointer?

Background:

I am using virtual tables to drive a SQLite interface to a set of external files. I am using SQLite mainly to get access to decent SQL querying and existing drivers for e.g. Python. I have defined a function `open_myfiles` which currently creates all the virtual tables based on the files in a given directory. The application just has to do `SELECT open_myfiles('/path/to/tables')` and the database is populated with the correct virtual tables.

However, I am attempting an improvement. Currently, the virtual tables are persisted to the current database and it is difficult to load multiple directories. I think that a better approach would be to attach each directory as a separate, named,  `:memory:` database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that there is no clear connection between a C api database ptr and an attached database. I had to modify my initial approach, and here is how I solved it in case anyone else stumbles upon this.

Instead of registering the virtual table module on extension load, I register a virtual table module for each invocation of the `open_myfiles` function. In addition to registering the module, this function also executes `ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS 'mymod'` to put the virtual tables in their respective namespace (`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` works with qualified names as well, it turns out).

All in all, it works very well. I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by passing the correct connection string. The important read is [this part](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) of the SQLite documentation:

1. If you specify an URI in the form `"file::memory:?cache=shared"`, then all memory DB will be shared
2. If you specify an URI in the form `"file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared"` then the DB will be a *named* in memory DB

Comment: Actually, the first one does not work according to the docs (https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html). The question is quite old so I am not sure shared cache existed back then.